# Wordpress child theme not overriding all files

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been working on customizations to a theme via a child theme and so far all has been well.

The Parent theme users the new customizer (files in inc/customizer) for visual theme settings in the wp-admin GUI.

When trying to replace these files the child theme simply doesn't override the parent themes files. Is this not possible?

If so. How would I go about adding options to the customizer or overriding the functions in these files?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like noone has alot of knowledge about how this actually works or what files are actually overrridden.

However. The correct method of overriding a function in a file that isn't automaticly overridden via filename is to just load that function into functions.php. Ugly, but it does work.